# Strapi closing connection to host before response

Tags: javascript, axios, strapi

I have a local Java Service that exposes a single endpoint where the response can take over 5min sometimes depending on the request size. I want to "hide" this endpoint behind Strapi, so that a user that is not authenticated through Strapi, can't access this endpoint. What i've done is, created a custom Route in Strapi, and created a custom controller function for this route:

```
async optimizeRoute(ctx) {
    try {
        console.log(`${new Date()} - Optimize route started`)
        const vehicles = ctx.request.body.vehicles.map(vehicle => {
            return {
                id: vehicle.id,
                licenseplate: vehicle.licenseplate,
                maxweight: vehicle.maxweight,
                maxlength: vehicle.maxlength,
                geojson: vehicle.geojson,
                maxtime: moment(vehicle.endtime).diff(moment(vehicle.starttime), 'seconds') * 1.1
            }
        });

        const orders = ctx.request.body.orders.map(order => {
            return {
                id: order.id,
                weight: order.weight,
                length: order.length,
                geojson: order.geojson
            }
        });
        console.log(`Using ${vehicles.length} vehicles, and ${orders.length} orders!`)
        const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:9090/optimizeroutes',
            { vehicles: vehicles, orders: orders }, {timeout: 0}
        );
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        ctx.throw(error.response.status, error.response);
    }
}
```

But what happens when i do this, is Strapi closes the connection after 1-2 min to the requester before the response is returned.
Using Strapi Beta3.17.5.
Anywhere i can configure or debug to wait for the axios to return a response then return the response to the requester??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default server timeout value is 2 min, Please check the image for reference.
[image]

So in `server.js` you can increase this timeout value by passing callback function

So the code will look like below

```js
const strapi = require('strapi');

strapi(/* {...} */).start(()=>{

    strapi.server.setTimeout(0); 
});
```

setting timeout to 0 strapi will wait forever or you can add value in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for putting me on the right track @NS23, but i couldn't user server.js to start my server, and console logging strapi.server returned undefined.

What i did though was access strapi.server in Bootstrap.js, which then logging strapi.server, could see the timeout was changed from 120000 to 0